# como fazer um filtro em um array no Swift similar ao like?

Tags: array, swift, filter

let cast = ["Vivien", "Marlon", "Kim", "Karl"]
gostaria de retornar like ('%ar%')
"resultado esperado [ "Marlon", "Karl"] "

Comment: Resolvido:
for i in 0..<cast.count {  
let texto = cast[i]  
  
if texto.lowercased().range(of:"ar") != nil{  
print(cast[i])  
}  
}

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `filter` do array para fazer isso. Segue exemplo:

```
import Foundation
let castArray = ["Vivien", "Marlon", "Kim", "Karl"]
let filtered = castArray.filter { $0.containsString("ar") }
print(filtered)
```

Espero ter ajudado. Valeu!